# Google Guava Invokedynamic requires --min-sdk-version >= 26

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin, android-studio-3.0

I am getting this **error** with Android Studio 3.0 (and another different with 2.3). I've been trying to fix removing some dependencies for hours and nothing worked. So now I do not want what else can I try.

```
    Error while processing com/google/common/collect/Maps$NavigableAsMapView.class
com.android.dx.cf.code.SimException: invalid opcode ba (invokedynamic requires --min-sdk-version >= 26)
```

This is my **gradle build**.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.costular.transmissionremote"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9'
    }
}

androidExtensions {
    experimental = true
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.11'
    kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.11'

    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.3'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxkotlin:2.1.0'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'

    implementation 'com.costular:kotlin-utils:0.1'
    implementation 'android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0-alpha9'
    implementation 'android.arch.persistence.room:rxjava2:1.0.0-alpha9'
    kapt "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0-alpha9"

    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.1'
    //implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:26.0.1'
    //testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.8.47'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    //androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.0'

    androidTestImplementation("com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.0", {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    //implementation files('libs/transmission-rpc-java_main.jar')
}
```

And my **root build**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.4-2'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-beta2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I would appreciate you if you could help me, guys.

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

**:app:dependencies**

```
implementation - Implementation only dependencies for 'main' sources. (n)
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-android-extensions-runtime:1.1.4-2 (n)
+--- unspecified (n)
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:1.1.4-2 (n)
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1 (n)
+--- com.android.support:design:26.0.1 (n)
+--- com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2 (n)
+--- com.google.dagger:dagger:2.11 (n)
+--- io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.3 (n)
+--- io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxkotlin:2.1.0 (n)
+--- io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1 (n)
+--- com.costular:kotlin-utils:0.1 (n)
+--- android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0-alpha9 (n)
+--- android.arch.persistence.room:rxjava2:1.0.0-alpha9 (n)
\--- com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.1 (n)

kapt
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-annotation-processing:1.1.4-2
|    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.1.4-2
|         \--- org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0
+--- com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.11
|    +--- com.google.dagger:dagger:2.11
|    |    \--- javax.inject:javax.inject:1
|    +--- com.google.dagger:dagger-producers:2.11
|    |    +--- com.google.dagger:dagger:2.11 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.1 -> 1.3.9
|    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:21.0
|    |    \--- javax.inject:javax.inject:1
|    +--- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.1 -> 1.3.9
|    +--- com.google.googlejavaformat:google-java-format:1.3
|    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:19.0 -> 21.0
|    |    \--- com.google.errorprone:javac:9-dev-r3297-1-shaded
|    +--- com.google.guava:guava:21.0
|    +--- com.squareup:javapoet:1.7.0 -> 1.8.0
|    \--- javax.inject:javax.inject:1
\--- android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0-alpha9
     +--- android.arch.persistence.room:common:1.0.0-alpha9
     |    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.0.0
     +--- android.arch.persistence.room:migration:1.0.0-alpha9
     |    +--- android.arch.persistence.room:common:1.0.0-alpha9 (*)
     |    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.1.3 -> 1.1.4-2 (*)
     |    \--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0
     +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.1.3 -> 1.1.4-2 (*)
     +--- com.google.auto:auto-common:0.6
     |    \--- com.google.guava:guava:18.0 -> 21.0
     +--- com.squareup:javapoet:1.8.0
     +--- org.antlr:antlr4:4.5.3
     +--- org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc:3.16.1
     \--- commons-codec:commons-codec:1.10

kaptAndroidTest
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-annotation-processing:1.1.4-2
|    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.1.4-2
|         \--- org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0
+--- com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.11
|    +--- com.google.dagger:dagger:2.11
|    |    \--- javax.inject:javax.inject:1
|    +--- com.google.dagger:dagger-producers:2.11
|    |    +--- com.google.dagger:dagger:2.11 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.1 -> 1.3.9
|    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:21.0
|    |    \--- javax.inject:javax.inject:1
|    +--- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.1 -> 1.3.9
|    +--- com.google.googlejavaformat:google-java-format:1.3
|    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:19.0 -> 21.0
|    |    \--- com.google.errorprone:javac:9-dev-r3297-1-shaded
|    +--- com.google.guava:guava:21.0
|    +--- com.squareup:javapoet:1.7.0 -> 1.8.0
|    \--- javax.inject:javax.inject:1
\--- android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0-alpha9
     +--- android.arch.persistence.room:common:1.0.0-alpha9
     |    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.0.0
     +--- android.arch.persistence.room:migration:1.0.0-alpha9
     |    +--- android.arch.persistence.room:common:1.0.0-alpha9 (*)
     |    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.1.3 -> 1.1.4-2 (*)
     |    \--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0
     +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.1.3 -> 1.1.4-2 (*)
     +--- com.google.auto:auto-common:0.6
     |    \--- com.google.guava:guava:18.0 -> 21.0
     +--- com.squareup:javapoet:1.8.0
     +--- org.antlr:antlr4:4.5.3
     +--- org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc:3.16.1
     \--- commons-codec:commons-codec:1.10

kaptDebug
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-annotation-processing:1.1.4-2
|    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.1.4-2
|         \--- org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0
+--- com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.11
|    +--- com.google.dagger:dagger:2.11
|    |    \--- javax.inject:javax.inject:1
|    +--- com.google.dagger:dagger-producers:2.11
|    |    +--- com.google.dagger:dagger:2.11 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.1 -> 1.3.9
|    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:21.0
|    |    \--- javax.inject:javax.inject:1
|    +--- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.1 -> 1.3.9
|    +--- com.google.googlejavaformat:google-java-format:1.3
|    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:19.0 -> 21.0
|    |    \--- com.google.errorprone:javac:9-dev-r3297-1-shaded
|    +--- com.google.guava:guava:21.0
|    +--- com.squareup:javapoet:1.7.0 -> 1.8.0
|    \--- javax.inject:javax.inject:1
\--- android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0-alpha9
     +--- android.arch.persistence.room:common:1.0.0-alpha9
     |    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.0.0
     +--- android.arch.persistence.room:migration:1.0.0-alpha9
     |    +--- android.arch.persistence.room:common:1.0.0-alpha9 (*)
     |    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.1.3 -> 1.1.4-2 (*)
     |    \--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0
     +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.1.3 -> 1.1.4-2 (*)
     +--- com.google.auto:auto-common:0.6
     |    \--- com.google.guava:guava:18.0 -> 21.0
     +--- com.squareup:javapoet:1.8.0
     +--- org.antlr:antlr4:4.5.3
     +--- org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc:3.16.1
     \--- commons-codec:commons-codec:1.10

kaptRelease
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-annotation-processing:1.1.4-2
|    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.1.4-2
|         \--- org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0
+--- com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.11
|    +--- com.google.dagger:dagger:2.11
|    |    \--- javax.inject:javax.inject:1
|    +--- com.google.dagger:dagger-producers:2.11
|    |    +--- com.google.dagger:dagger:2.11 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.1 -> 1.3.9
|    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:21.0
|    |    \--- javax.inject:javax.inject:1
|    +--- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.1 -> 1.3.9
|    +--- com.google.googlejavaformat:google-java-format:1.3
|    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:19.0 -> 21.0
|    |    \--- com.google.errorprone:javac:9-dev-r3297-1-shaded
|    +--- com.google.guava:guava:21.0
|    +--- com.squareup:javapoet:1.7.0 -> 1.8.0
|    \--- javax.inject:javax.inject:1
\--- android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0-alpha9
     +--- android.arch.persistence.room:common:1.0.0-alpha9
     |    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.0.0
     +--- android.arch.persistence.room:migration:1.0.0-alpha9
     |    +--- android.arch.persistence.room:common:1.0.0-alpha9 (*)
     |    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.1.3 -> 1.1.4-2 (*)
     |    \--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0
     +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.1.3 -> 1.1.4-2 (*)
     +--- com.google.auto:auto-common:0.6
     |    \--- com.google.guava:guava:18.0 -> 21.0
     +--- com.squareup:javapoet:1.8.0
     +--- org.antlr:antlr4:4.5.3
     +--- org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc:3.16.1
     \--- commons-codec:commons-codec:1.10

kaptTest
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-annotation-processing:1.1.4-2
|    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.1.4-2
|         \--- org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0
+--- com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.11
|    +--- com.google.dagger:dagger:2.11
|    |    \--- javax.inject:javax.inject:1
|    +--- com.google.dagger:dagger-producers:2.11
|    |    +--- com.google.dagger:dagger:2.11 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.1 -> 1.3.9
|    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:21.0
|    |    \--- javax.inject:javax.inject:1
|    +--- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.1 -> 1.3.9
|    +--- com.google.googlejavaformat:google-java-format:1.3
|    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:19.0 -> 21.0
|    |    \--- com.google.errorprone:javac:9-dev-r3297-1-shaded
|    +--- com.google.guava:guava:21.0
|    +--- com.squareup:javapoet:1.7.0 -> 1.8.0
|    \--- javax.inject:javax.inject:1
\--- android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0-alpha9
     +--- android.arch.persistence.room:common:1.0.0-alpha9
     |    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.0.0
     +--- android.arch.persistence.room:migration:1.0.0-alpha9
     |    +--- android.arch.persistence.room:common:1.0.0-alpha9 (*)
     |    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.1.3 -> 1.1.4-2 (*)
     |    \--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0
     +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.1.3 -> 1.1.4-2 (*)
     +--- com.google.auto:auto-common:0.6
     |    \--- com.google.guava:guava:18.0 -> 21.0
     +--- com.squareup:javapoet:1.8.0
     +--- org.antlr:antlr4:4.5.3
     +--- org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc:3.16.1
     \--- commons-codec:commons-codec:1.10

kaptTestDebug
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-annotation-processing:1.1.4-2
|    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.1.4-2
|         \--- org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0
+--- com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.11
|    +--- com.google.dagger:dagger:2.11
|    |    \--- javax.inject:javax.inject:1
|    +--- com.google.dagger:dagger-producers:2.11
|    |    +--- com.google.dagger:dagger:2.11 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.1 -> 1.3.9
|    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:21.0
|    |    \--- javax.inject:javax.inject:1
|    +--- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.1 -> 1.3.9
|    +--- com.google.googlejavaformat:google-java-format:1.3
|    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:19.0 -> 21.0
|    |    \--- com.google.errorprone:javac:9-dev-r3297-1-shaded
|    +--- com.google.guava:guava:21.0
|    +--- com.squareup:javapoet:1.7.0 -> 1.8.0
|    \--- javax.inject:javax.inject:1
\--- android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0-alpha9
     +--- android.arch.persistence.room:common:1.0.0-alpha9
     |    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.0.0
     +--- android.arch.persistence.room:migration:1.0.0-alpha9
     |    +--- android.arch.persistence.room:common:1.0.0-alpha9 (*)
     |    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.1.3 -> 1.1.4-2 (*)
     |    \--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0
     +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.1.3 -> 1.1.4-2 (*)
     +--- com.google.auto:auto-common:0.6
     |    \--- com.google.guava:guava:18.0 -> 21.0
     +--- com.squareup:javapoet:1.8.0
     +--- org.antlr:antlr4:4.5.3
     +--- org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc:3.16.1
     \--- commons-codec:commons-codec:1.10

kaptTestRelease
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-annotation-processing:1.1.4-2
|    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.1.4-2
|         \--- org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0
+--- com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.11
|    +--- com.google.dagger:dagger:2.11
|    |    \--- javax.inject:javax.inject:1
|    +--- com.google.dagger:dagger-producers:2.11
|    |    +--- com.google.dagger:dagger:2.11 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.1 -> 1.3.9
|    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:21.0
|    |    \--- javax.inject:javax.inject:1
|    +--- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.1 -> 1.3.9
|    +--- com.google.googlejavaformat:google-java-format:1.3
|    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:19.0 -> 21.0
|    |    \--- com.google.errorprone:javac:9-dev-r3297-1-shaded
|    +--- com.google.guava:guava:21.0
|    +--- com.squareup:javapoet:1.7.0 -> 1.8.0
|    \--- javax.inject:javax.inject:1
\--- android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0-alpha9
     +--- android.arch.persistence.room:common:1.0.0-alpha9
     |    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.0.0
     +--- android.arch.persistence.room:migration:1.0.0-alpha9
     |    +--- android.arch.persistence.room:common:1.0.0-alpha9 (*)
     |    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.1.3 -> 1.1.4-2 (*)
     |    \--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0
     +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.1.3 -> 1.1.4-2 (*)
     +--- com.google.auto:auto-common:0.6
     |    \--- com.google.guava:guava:18.0 -> 21.0
     +--- com.squareup:javapoet:1.8.0
     +--- org.antlr:antlr4:4.5.3
     +--- org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc:3.16.1
     \--- commons-codec:commons-codec:1.10
```

Comment: That looks to be caused by a transitive guava dependency, that was compiled for Java 8. To see where it's coming from, run the following: `./gradlew :<module-name>:dependencyInsight --configuration debugCompileClasspath --dependency guava` (replace `module-name` with the name of your app module). The output should be easy to interpret.

Comment: It returns:

No dependencies matching given input were found in configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'

Comment: Can you also try `./gradlew -q :<module-name>:dependencies`?

Comment: Room and Dagger use guava v21 but I've never had any errors before. I updated my question with the log.

Answer (score 2):

```
implementation "com.google.guava:guava:23.0"
```

Instead of

```
implementation "com.google.guava:guava:23.0-android"
```